# SQL union needs to return Value in Single column for Calculations

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am not getting through the requirement of getting the output in single column for calculation. The calculation suppose to return the difference between two timestamps.

```
select (cast(fech1 as timestamp) - cast(fech2 as timestamp) )total
from
(
select MIN(t_stamp) fech1 from alllog where message='Log A Starts Here' 
and Application = 'NET' 
and component='ABC'
and transID='291-123'
AND TRUNC(Time_Stamp) >= to_date('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') 
and TRUNC(Time_Stamp) <= TO_DATE('30-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
group by transID
Union all                                                                                                                                
select  MAX(t_stamp) fech2 from alllog where message='Log A Ends here' 
and Application = 'NET' 
and component='ABC'
and transID='291-123'
AND TRUNC(Time_Stamp) >= to_date('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') 
and TRUNC(Time_Stamp) <= TO_DATE('30-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
group by transID

)
```

The result is displayed in different rows. This is why due to single column the outer query is not getting the dat for outer query. (as it only get Fech1 not fech 2).
The t_stam is date field. Oracle timestamp function can cast it into timestamp and give the difference. If there is no query I can use, Kindly help me with a procedure may be.

I am using Oracle.

Comment: Timestamp- and date- handling varies a lot between vendors. If you are  trying to find an expression that will work for all vendors that you have tagged your question with, I suspect it will be rather difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a UNION is what you're looking for here. It looks like you're just looking for the MIN and MAX value of timestamps with the correct message within each group, something like (the untested);

```
select (cast(fech1 as timestamp) - cast(fech2 as timestamp) )total
from
(
   select MIN(CASE WHEN message='Log A Starts Here' THEN t_stamp END) fech1,
          MAX(CASE WHEN message='Log A Ends here'   THEN t_stamp END) fech2
   from alllog 
   where Application = 'NET' 
     and component='ABC'
     and transID='291-123'
     AND TRUNC(Time_Stamp) >= to_date('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') 
     and TRUNC(Time_Stamp) <= TO_DATE('30-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
   group by transID
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working. This is what I was looking for.  My only doubt is if I am executing the query on a specific date range and between that date range I have multiple start and end message of same kind, how shell I calculate dynamically the start and end message time difference for each pair.

Comment: @SOAMad If you need to pair start/stop pairs, the query will be a bit more tricky since there need to be rules for what happens with a lost start or stop message, duplicates etc. You may want to post a new question with some sample data and a desired result to get a good answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is something like

```
SELECT (cast(Min.fech1 as timestamp) - cast(Max.fech2 as timestamp) )total
FROM 
(
    select  MIN(t_stamp) fech1, transID
    from alllog 
    where message='Log A Starts Here' 
        and Application = 'NET' 
        and component='ABC'
        and transID='291-123'
        AND TRUNC(Time_Stamp) >= to_date('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') 
        and TRUNC(Time_Stamp) <= TO_DATE('30-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
    group by transID) as Min
JOIN (                                                                                              
    select  MAX(t_stamp) fech2, transID
    from alllog 
    where message='Log A Ends here' 
        and Application = 'NET' 
        and component='ABC'
        and transID='291-123'
        AND TRUNC(Time_Stamp) >= to_date('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') 
        and TRUNC(Time_Stamp) <= TO_DATE('30-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
    group by transID) as Max on Min.transID = Max.transID
```

**EDIT:** I think Joachim's answer is more efficient, because all your filter conditions are the same. In fact you can do it without the outer select.

```
select 
    (MIN(CASE WHEN message='Log A Starts Here' THEN CAST(t_stamp as timestamp) END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN message='Log A Ends here' THEN CAST(t_stamp as timestamp)END)) as Total
from alllog 
where Application = 'NET' 
    and component='ABC'
    and transID='291-123'
    AND TRUNC(Time_Stamp) >= to_date('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') 
    and TRUNC(Time_Stamp) <= TO_DATE('30-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
group by transID
```